# Sum over integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I've seen many times the expression

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k$$ and I wonder what's the true interpretation of that. By definition if we set $s_N = \sum_{k = 0}^N a_k$ then $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k = \lim_{N \to \infty} s_N $$

Based on that, I guess $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{-k}$$ If this is the case could we also say $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k = \lim_{N\to \infty}s_N$$ where $s_N = \sum_{k = -N}^{N}a_k$ ? It seems to be similar to principal value and if that's true they are not always equal.

Comment: I think this answer might be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576317/notation-of-double-sided-infinite-sum

Comment: @NDewolf I don't agree with the approved answer in that post. The meaning of this sum depends on the context and the second interpretation by OP is also used sometimes.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If both series converge(i.e. positive and negative parts), can we conclude that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k = \lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{k = -N}^{N}a_k$?

Comment: @S.H.W Yes, for sure.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The second answer on the question I referred to does give a decent analysis, no?

Comment: @NDewolf I don't get the need for absolute convergence there. Why not convergence?

Comment: I can't tell for sure (this is why did not reply with an answer but with a comment). I assume it has to do with the common reasons for requiring absolute convergence of series (rearrangements, etc)